# Generate a subplot with ylim in df.boxplot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, subplot

I have the following code:

```
df.boxplot(column = ['rate'], by = 'age', figsize=(9,7))
```

However, this boxplot has an outlier that shows really small the boxes. I need to code the following:

```
#1st Subplot
df.boxplot(column = ['rate'], by = 'age', figsize=(9,7))

#2nd Subplot
df.boxplot(column = ['rate'], by = 'age', figsize=(9,7))
plt.ylim(0,2)
```

So this means I need a 2x1 or 1x2 subplots to show:
#1 Original boxplot and #2 A zoom boxplot (ylim(0,2))

¿How can I approach this subplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing the subplot axes to the pandas plots explicitly, then you can adjust their limits individually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axarray = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(9, 7))

#1st Subplot
df.boxplot(column=['rate'], by='age', ax=axarray[0])

#2nd Subplot
df.boxplot(column=['rate'], by='age', ax=axarray[1])

axarray[1].set_ylim(bottom=0, top=2)
```